# Select results where joined table contains records with an attribute, but without another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

```
Example.joins(another: :things).where(examples: {status: 'active'}, things: {status: 'required'}).where.not(things: {status: 'unwanted'})
```

The result from the query above is the same with or without the "where.not".

Things may have different statuses: 'required', 'unwanted' and many others.  I must fetch Example records that contain at least one thing with 'required' status, but exclude records that contain one or more thing with 'unwanted' status.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this problem to solve using 2 queries. Rails [form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) will be helpful in this case.

```
another_ids = Example.from(Another.join(:things)
                     .group(:status)
                     .where(status: [ 'required', 'indifferent'])
                     .select('status, distinct anothers.id as another_id'), :x)
                     .pluck("x.another_id")
```

then,

```
Example.where(another_id: another_ids).all
```

Here is the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79959/r-o-r) conversations which leads to this answer.

Comment: @Ney what is the datatype of `status` of `things` tables,,?

Comment: how then a thing record will have a both `status` ? It should be a single status at any point of time.

Comment: The 'another' object may contain multiple things. Each thing has a status. One of them must have the 'required' status, but if one of them has the 'unwanted' status, I must skip it.

Comment: I had to remove the quotes for the subquery and I'm also getting _syntax error at or near "distinct"_. Besides, I found out Things may have various other status, which makes it hard to list them all in the where method.

Comment: @Ney yes remove `"`.. that's a typo there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80056/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-ney).